# User.identity.Name is null - configure name with azure authentication .net 4.7

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, owin-middleware

I have an application that is in .net 4.7 and i am wanting to bring authentication over to use Azure AD from windows authentication.
I have this working but i want to use User.Identity.Name which is currently null

I have seen that i can configure this somehow within startup.cs in configuration using NameClaimTypeReceiver

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    NameClaimTypeRetriever = OnNameClaimTypeRetriever
                }
```

I cant see an example of writing this method  anywhere OnNameClaimTypeRetriever

would you please be able to provide an example.

I am wanting to set it to OnPremisesSamAccountName which i can get via azure graph

Answer (score 0):

NameClaimTypeRetriever is invoked from [TokenValidationParameters.CreateClaimsIdentity(SecurityToken securityToken, string issuer)](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/c8aa8acc78ebc5227e95ae0f3be7c2526b0e9633/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/TokenValidationParameters.cs#L330) using those same parameters.

Example:

```cs
    NameClaimTypeRetriever = (SecurityToken securityToken, string issuer) =>
    {
        var validUserNameTokens = new[] { "preferred_username", JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email };
        return validUserNameTokens.FirstOrDefault(token => (securityToken as JwtSecurityToken).Claims.Any(claim => token == claim.Type));
    }
```

This checks for any claim which type is either 'preferred_username' or 'email'. If not present, returning null makes CreateClaimsIdentity() use ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType instead.